# Why my combination function doesn't print large numbers correctly when I remove decimal points? (in Lua)

Tags: printing, lua, combinations, largenumber

To print big number correctly - without things like e+ - in lua, what do I need to do? Also, how can I remove decimal point numbers like 123456.0 without using math.floor()?

I made a combination function for a, b under 100.
 First, I made with factorial function but it occurs overflow. So, I made it with factional decomposition. The range is under 100, so I grab prime numbers under 100 and made it.

```lua
local n, m = io.read("*n", "*n")

local prime = {2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31,
 37, 41, 43, 47, 53, 59, 61, 67, 71, 73, 79, 83, 89, 97}

function make_case()
    local prime_case = {}

    for i, v in ipairs(prime) do
        prime_case[i] = {v, 0}
    end
    return prime_case
end

function fact(n, m, ans)
    local case = ans
    for i = m, n do
        if i ~= 0 then
            local num = i
            for j, v in ipairs(case) do
                repeat
                    if num % v[1] == 0 then
                        num = num / v[1]
                        case[j][2] = case[j][2] + 1
                    else
                        break
                    end
                until num % v[1] ~= 0
                if num == 1 then
                    break
                end
            end
        end
    end
    return case
end

if n-m > m then
    m = n - m
end

local top_case = make_case()
local bot_case = make_case()

local top = fact(n, m+1, top_case)
local bot = fact(n-m, 0, bot_case)

local tot = 1

for i, v in ipairs(top) do
    --print(v[1], v[2], bot[i][2])
    top[i][2] = top[i][2] - bot[i][2]
    tot = tot * (top[i][1]^top[i][2])
end

print(math.floor(tot))
```

I tried 64 40 as the input value, I get the result 2.5064910546967e+17 (when I print only tot). I don't want to see the decimal points in this result, so I put math.floor on the result. This results 250649105469666112, but the last 2 digits are wrong. The correct answer of that input is 250649105469666100.

Other small inputs work pretty well, so I think this problem is from printing. How can I print big numbers one digit by one digit?

Comment: The problem is the exponentiation, which always returns a double. The correct answer of that input seems to be 250649105469666120, which cannot be represented exactly as a double.

Comment: To print float without decimal point and without exp: `print(("%.f"):format(x))`

Comment: But if your number is greater than `2^53` then you might already lost the precision.